# How can cast the string to json using C#?

Tags: c#, json

One string like this：

```
[["0.45842413","10"],["0.45850028","11"],["0.46092215","10"],["0.478999","133.69218728"]]
```

after cast  like this:

```
[["Price":"0.45842413","Amount":"10"],["Price":"0.45850028","Amount":"11"],["Price":"0.46092215","Amount":"10"],["Price":"0.478999","Amount":"133.69218728"]]
```

Comment: the question is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, both strings are JSON
You're basically asking how to cast from one format of JSON to another.
The best way to do it would be to

1. Deserialise the initial JSON into the immediate data structure -> List of arrays
2. Convert that data structure into a data structure that represents the structure of your data -> List of objects that have Price and Amount fields
3. Serialize that object back into JSON

[image]

Comment: Please Don't post images of code. Surely it is more difficult than simply copy pasting code into the text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Regex.Replace` with capture groups to insert "Price" and "Amount" into your string.

Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        string data = "[[\"0.45842413\",\"10\"],[\"0.45850028\",\"11\"],[\"0.46092215\",\"10\"],[\"0.478999\",\"133.69218728\"]]";
        data = Regex.Replace(data, "(\"\\d+[.]{0,1}\\d{0,}\"),(\"\\d+[.]{0,1}\\d{0,}\")", "\"Price\":$1,\"Amount\":$2");
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[["Price":"0.45842413","Amount":"10"],["Price":"0.45850028","Amount":"11"],["Price":"0.46092215","Amount":"10"],["Price":"0.478999","Amount":"133.69218728"]]
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ilmG9C)